# Selector not working after adding new element to DOM in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

I have a div with ID 'content'. Into this div located text input and span with date. Into a span i wrote added date of content. For this span i used Timeago plugin to every minute updating difference of current time with added. When I update this content jQuery not select new added element. What I must do? This is code:
HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
    <input id="text" type="text" name="yourName"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeContent();">Change</button>
    <span class="timeago" title="2014-03-30 20:04"></span>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    function changeContent() {
        var content = $('#content');
        var value = $('#text').val();
        var spanElm = $('span.timeago');
        $.ajax({
            url:'/ajax/change.php',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {"text":value},
            success: function (data) {
                spanElm.remove();
                content.append(data);
            }
        });
    }
    jQuery(function($) {
        jQuery("span.timeago").timeago([]);
    });
</script>
```

Ajax returns me a span element with new date. Example: `<span class="timeago" title="2014-03-30 20:07"></span>`.

Comment: Anytime that you add elements dynamically you should use the on() handler. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thank you Jay for suggestion it works on me!

Answer (score 1):

Use this `jQuery("span.timeago").timeago([]);` inside `success` callback.

Because ajax is asynchronous in nature.

Full code:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    function changeContent() {
        var content = $('#content');
        var value = $('#text').val();
        var spanElm = $('span.timeago');
        $.ajax({
            url:'/ajax/change.php',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {"text":value},
            success: function (data) {
                spanElm.remove();
                content.append(data);
                jQuery("span.timeago").timeago([]);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```